# Maximum number of external Hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

What would be the maximum number of external hdds I could connect via usb 3.0 hubs, specifically https://www.seagate.com/au/en/products/external-hard-drives/expansion-external-drives/

I'll be using the desktop version which has it's own power supply, this means I could use unpowered hubs right?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

USB supports 127 devices. This includes hubs etc.

However, I would imagine in the real world you would saturate the bus long before reaching that figure.